# Where do i download the effects file?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I was working on this site tutorials and on this line:

```
http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series1/Terrain_from_file.php

effect = Content.Load<Effect>("effects");
```

Im getting an error file not found on effects.
Error loading "effects". File not found

Where do i download the effects file at all ? Can't find any link to get the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe if you read the first page of the tutorial you would have found it :)

http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/series1.php